# How to keep multiple listviews' items selected in a Win forms app

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I have what I hope to be an easy solution for you fine, intelligent folks. I have a Windows form app (C#) and it has 2 listviews. The user will choose at least one item from listview1 (we will call it people) and at least one item from listview2 (we will call it offices). The point is to assign people to offices and save that in a DB.

The issue is that once they select an item(s) from one listview and click anything on the other listview, it clears the displayed choices from the initial listview. I know I can grab the info programmatically but the user is going to think that their choices from the first listview were erased. Any ideas on how to keep the selections on the first listview visible?

Update: Here is a screenshot of the app so far: (it says I need 1`0 rep before I can post an image so I will just link to it)
http://s17.postimg.org/wcajg7o4v/Untitled.png

The user clicks an office and then clicks a case(s) and I make an entry in the db to persist their IDs. The issue is that if I click an office and then do anything in the other listview (Cases) then the items I selected in Offices are no longer visible. The code is over 1500 lines and counting so I am unsure exactly what code you need. The only manipulation I am using of the listviews is a sorting method and populating them of course. Here is that code (or some of it). The loadOfficeList method populates the Offices listview and the class below it is my sorting class for all listviews (with their own respective objects, of course).

```
        private void loadOfficeList()
    {
        listViewOffices.Clear();
        listViewOffices.Items.Clear();
        DataTable t = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            c.Open();
            // 2
            // Create new DataAdapter
            using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter("select ID, Name from Offices where deleted = 'false'", c))
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                a.Fill(ds);
                t = ds.Tables[0];
            }//end inner using
        }//end outer using

        // Set DataSource property of ListBox as DataSet's DefaultView

        this.listViewOffices.TabIndex = 0;
        this.listViewOffices.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.List;
        ColumnHeader colHead;

        colHead = new ColumnHeader();
        colHead.Width = 250;
        colHead.Text = "Office Name";
        this.listViewOffices.Columns.Add(colHead);


        colHead = new ColumnHeader();
        colHead.Width = 40;
        colHead.Text = "ID";
        this.listViewOffices.Columns.Add(colHead);

        ListViewItem lvi;
        ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem lvsi;

        foreach (DataRow dataRow in t.Rows)
        {

            lvi = new ListViewItem();
            lvi.Text = dataRow["Name"].ToString();
            lvi.Tag = dataRow["Name"].ToString();

            lvsi = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem();
            lvsi.Text = dataRow["ID"].ToString();
            lvi.SubItems.Add(lvsi);


            this.listViewOffices.Items.Add(lvi);
            this.listViewOffices.EndUpdate();

            this.listViewOffices.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;

        }//end foreach

    }//end method

public class ListViewColumnSorter : IComparer
{
    // Specifies the column to be sorted
    private int ColumnToSort;

    // Specifies the order in which to sort (i.e. 'Ascending').
    private SortOrder OrderOfSort;

    // Case insensitive comparer object
    private CaseInsensitiveComparer ObjectCompare;


    // Class constructor.  Initializes various elements
    public ListViewColumnSorter()
    {
        // Initialize the column to '0'
        ColumnToSort = 0;

        // Initialize the sort order to 'none'
        OrderOfSort = SortOrder.None;

        // Initialize the CaseInsensitiveComparer object
        ObjectCompare = new CaseInsensitiveComparer();
    }//end constructor


    // This method is inherited from the IComparer interface.  It compares the two objects passed using a case insensitive comparison.
    // <returns>The result of the comparison. "0" if equal, negative if 'x' is less than 'y' and positive if 'x' is greater than 'y'</returns>
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        int compareResult;
        ListViewItem listviewX, listviewY;

        // Cast the objects to be compared to ListViewItem objects
        listviewX = (ListViewItem)x;
        listviewY = (ListViewItem)y;

        compareResult = ObjectCompare.Compare(listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text, listviewY.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text);

        // Calculate correct return value based on object comparison
        if (OrderOfSort == SortOrder.Ascending)
            return compareResult;
        else if (OrderOfSort == SortOrder.Descending)
            return (-compareResult);
        else
            return 0;
    }//end method

    // Gets or sets the number of the column to which to apply the sorting operation (Defaults to '0').
    public int SortColumn
    {
        set
        { ColumnToSort = value; }
        get
        { return ColumnToSort; }
    }//end method

    // Gets or sets the order of sorting to apply (for example, 'Ascending' or 'Descending').
    public SortOrder Order
    {
        set
        { OrderOfSort = value; }
        get
        { return OrderOfSort; }
    }//end method

}//end class
```

Thanks in advance!

Dan

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you're describing, that sounds like the job of the [HideSelection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.hideselection%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property?

From MSDN:

> ListView.HideSelection Property
>
> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the selected item in the control remains highlighted when the control loses focus.
>
> true if the selected item does not appear highlighted when the control loses focus; false if the selected item still appears highlighted when the control loses focus. The default is true.

Comment: Hi! That does persist the selection if the user clicks other items but if you click in another listview, it does not persist the selection. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @user2883140 Perhaps you should post your code and or a screenshot of what you're talking about? I just created a temp project with two listviews with dummy items in them, set the HideSelection property on them to false, ran it, selected an item in the first one, then clicked on and selected an item in the second one, and the item in the first one did still display as selected (though greyed out to show that it didn't have focus), and the count of how many items were selected in each was also correct?

Comment: Updated with a screencap and my code with additional details. Thanks to all who are helping me!

Comment: To anyone with this issue, I simply added a single checkbox field to one of the listviews and that solved my issue:
this.listView1.CheckBoxes = true;

Answer (score 0):

why not use a listbox instead.  I did the following test case and it worked for listbox

```
listBox1.Items.Add("listbox1 item1");
listBox1.Items.Add("listbox1 item2");
listBox1.Items.Add("listbox1 item3");
listBox1.Items.Add("listbox1 item4");



listBox2.Items.Add("listbox2 item1");
listBox2.Items.Add("listbox2 item2");
listBox2.Items.Add("listbox2 item3");
listBox2.Items.Add("listbox2 item4");


listView1.Items.Add("listview1 item1");
listView1.Items.Add("listview1 item2");
listView1.Items.Add("listview1 item3");
listView1.Items.Add("listview1 item4");



listView2.Items.Add("listview2 item1");
listView2.Items.Add("listview2 item2");
listView2.Items.Add("listview2 item3");
listView2.Items.Add("listview2 item4");
```

![screenshot of example]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZiK6.png